# ¿Cómo optimizar carga de imágenes en Asp .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una aplicación con asp net en la cual tengo un registro de usuarios, obtengo información de ellos además de un archivo jpeg correspondiente a su foto, esta información la recibo en una api, lo siguiente es codificar la imagen en base64 para guardar esta cadena en la base de datos junto con su demás información, el método para hacer esto es:

```
var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
string photo = "";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  file.CopyTo(ms);
  var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
  photo = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
}
Users usr = new Users();
usr.Photo = "data:" + file.ContentType + ";base64," + photo;
```

ahora bien el problema que tengo es que no tengo control sobre la calidad/peso de éstas imagenes por lo que el string del base64 es demasiado extenso, esto al hacer una petición de la lista de mis usuarios tarda demasiado en cargar (5-8min con 300 usuarios aprox).
¿Hay alguna manera de reducir el tamaño/peso de la imagen para que de esta manera el base64 sea más corto y se pueda optimizar la carga de la información?

el método ajax para enviar la informacion es:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var photo = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];
        formData.append("file", photo);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/api/UsersApiController/CreateUser',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: formData,
complete: function (status) {}
```

y el método en back para guardar la información del usuario:

```
public void RegistrarAcompanante(int idUser, int idGuest)
    {
        using (WeddingAppContext contexto = new WeddingAppContext())
        {
            try
            {
                
                UsersGuests guests = new UsersGuests();
                guests.IdUser = idUser;
                guests.IdGuest = idGuest;
                contexto.UsersGuests.Add(guests);
                contexto.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Agrega como estas consumiendo el servicio, aqui parace que estas obteniendo la foto desde un form, no se porque dices que no tienes el control., en cuanto a manipular el tamaño, peso

Comment: Tu pagina de cargar imagen y tu manera de guardar codigo es el backend de tu pagina?

Comment: en efecto, estoy obteniendo la imagen y los datos del usuario desde un formulario utilizando una peticion ajax:

Comment: Como puedes ver tu obtienes la imagen "file" antes de convertirla base64 puedes redimensionarla, usando javascript puedes hacerlo de lado de la pagina si es que estas implementando una pagino o  tambien del lado del servidor.

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Recibir o transformar imágenes a base64 siempre expande el peso de las mismas. 2. Una estrategia que funciona bien es almacenar la ruta de las imágenes y éstas se quedan almacenadas en algún lugar del disco duro del servidor o a nivel de red en una carpeta compartida exclusivamente para ese fin. 3. Una alternativa es utilizar un 3rd party como TinyPNG o Cloudinary que tienen esa funcionalidad lista que deseas emplear. Saludos.